# Apache Spark: Hangs on Broadcast

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, mapreduce, apache-spark-sql

I'm having a hard time debugging my Spark 1.6.2 application on Yarn. It is running in client-mode. Essentially it is locking up without crashing and the logs in the console are as shown below when it locks up.

```
17/03/31 20:12:02 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on p3plcdsh007.prod.phx3.gdg:47579 (size: 26.7 KB, free: 511.1 MB)
    17/03/31 20:12:03 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_3_piece0 in memory on p3plcdsh011.prod.phx3.gdg:63228 (size: 5.4 KB, free: 511.1 MB)
    17/03/31 20:12:03 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_4_piece0 in memory on p3plcdsh015.prod.phx3.gdg:9377 (size: 5.4 KB, free: 511.1 MB)
    17/03/31 20:12:03 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_4_piece0 in memory on p3plcdsh015.prod.phx3.gdg:61897 (size: 5.4 KB, free: 511.1 MB)
    17/03/31 20:12:03 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on p3plcdsh002.prod.phx3.gdg:23170 (size: 26.7 KB, free: 511.1 MB)
    17/03/31 20:12:03 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_3_piece0 in memory on p3plcdsh016.prod.phx3.gdg:16649 (size: 5.4 KB, free: 511.1 MB)
    17/03/31 20:12:04 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on p3plcdsh003.prod.phx3.gdg:55147 (size: 26.7 KB, free: 511.1 MB)
    17/03/31 20:12:04 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_4_piece0 in memory on p3plcdsh008.prod.phx3.gdg:7619 (size: 5.4 KB, free: 511.1 MB)
    17/03/31 20:12:04 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on p3plcdsh003.prod.phx3.gdg:40830 (size: 26.7 KB, free: 511.1 MB)
    17/03/31 20:12:04 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on p3plcdsh011.prod.phx3.gdg:20056 (size: 26.7 KB, free: 511.1 MB)
    17/03/31 20:12:04 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on p3plcdsh008.prod.phx3.gdg:47385 (size: 26.7 KB, free: 511.1 MB)
    17/03/31 20:12:04 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on p3plcdsh003.prod.phx3.gdg:2063 (size: 26.7 KB, free: 511.1 MB)
    17/03/31 20:12:04 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on p3plcdsh011.prod.phx3.gdg:63228 (size: 26.7 KB, free: 511.1 MB)
    17/03/31 20:12:04 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on p3plcdsh008.prod.phx3.gdg:64036 (size: 26.7 KB, free: 511.1 MB)
    17/03/31 20:12:05 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on p3plcdsh016.prod.phx3.gdg:16649 (size: 26.7 KB, free: 511.1 MB)
    17/03/31 20:12:05 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on p3plcdsh013.prod.phx3.gdg:31979 (size: 26.7 KB, free: 511.1 MB)
    17/03/31 20:12:05 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on p3plcdsh013.prod.phx3.gdg:18407 (size: 26.7 KB, free: 511.1 MB)
    17/03/31 20:12:05 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on p3plcdsh004.prod.phx3.gdg:45536 (size: 26.7 KB, free: 511.1 MB)
    17/03/31 20:12:05 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on p3plcdsh008.prod.phx3.gdg:50826 (size: 26.7 KB, free: 511.1 MB)
    17/03/31 20:12:06 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on p3plcdsh015.prod.phx3.gdg:36247 (size: 26.7 KB, free: 511.1 MB)
    17/03/31 20:12:06 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on p3plcdsh015.prod.phx3.gdg:22848 (size: 26.7 KB, free: 511.1 MB)
    17/03/31 20:12:06 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on p3plcdsh015.prod.phx3.gdg:9377 (size: 26.7 KB, free: 511.1 MB)
    17/03/31 20:12:06 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on p3plcdsh015.prod.phx3.gdg:61897 (size: 26.7 KB, free: 511.1 MB)
    17/03/31 20:12:07 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on p3plcdsh008.prod.phx3.gdg:7619 (size: 26.7 KB, free: 511.1 MB)
```

In the Spark UI, the lockup occurs at either a map or filter function.

Has anyone see this occur before or knows how to debug the situation?

It looks like it might be due to a memory issue or space issue, but there's no clear indication that it is. I can try and bump the memory up and see if that it helps, but does anyone have a tip to debug?

Thank you

Comment: What are you broadcasting?

Comment: Debugging the issue it looks like a fairly largeish Java object (something that is backed by a file 300mb uncompressed) ... but it serializes otherwise I would see a crash issue about serialization @Vidya. Is there a limit to the size of the object that can be serialized or a way to bump up the max size of the object?

Comment: seeing same issue .. Broadcast object is pretty small in size for me.

Comment: did this issue solve for you ?  I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Merely being serializable isn't enough. The problem could be a lot of things: your serialization mechanism (Java serialization is bad; Kryo is much better; and so on), your machine memory, making sure you use the broadcast value and not the wrapped value, etc.

There is also the Spark configuration `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold`:

"*Configures the maximum size in bytes for a table that will be broadcast to all worker nodes when performing a join. By setting this value to -1 broadcasting can be disabled. Note that currently statistics are only supported for Hive Metastore tables where the command ANALYZE TABLE  COMPUTE STATISTICS noscan has been run.*"

The default is 10MB serialized.

Finally, if you remove that default limitation and you have plenty of memory, you still prefer the size to be less than your largest RDD/DataFrame, which you can check with `SizeEstimator`:

```
import org.apache.spark.util.SizeEstimator._

logInfo(estimate(rdd))
```

In the end, if worse comes to worst, I would look into doing lookups from a lightning-fast cache datastore in your transformations rather than broadcasting this file.